# Determine if a series diverges or not

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $a_n > 0$ for all $n$, and the partial sum $s_n < 10$, then does $a_n$ converge?

By "for all $n$", I just mean for each $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4,..., a_n$, same goes for $s_n$. To me this doesn't really make sense since I always understood the partial sum $s_n$ to be $s_n = a_1+a_2+...+a_n$, which means that if $s_n<10$ for any arbitrary $n$, then the series converges for sure (unless it diverges to $-\infty$ or something similar to $(-1)^n$). To give it a charitable interpretation, I will assume that $s_n<10$. In this case, $\sum a_n$ has to diverge right? There is a restriction with $a_n > 0$, and if $a_n > 0$ for any arbitrary $n$, then the series will add up to be infinity? Which then diverges.

Comment: The partial sum is $s_n = a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n$, not $s_1 + s_2 + ... +s_n$. The positivity of the terms ensures $s_n$ is monotonic and $s_n < 10$ ensures it's bounded.

Comment: Right, some notation error there. But does the series converge?

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi that's a good point. Thank you

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi I see that the given restrictions $a_n > 0$ and $s_n < 10$ are satisfied, so it indeed does answer my question